# HttpStatus 404: The resorce is not available in Tomcat8

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am new to maven and trying to create a simple Login application using Spring and AngularJS. My project's name is ProMgmtPortal.

R-click on the project->Run As -> Maven Install :
the project gets successfully built.

[image: Build sucessful]
R-click on the project -> Run As -> Run on Server :

It gives the error- 
**HttpStatus 404- The requested resource is not available.**

[image: console]

I am using apache tomcat 8.0.36 server with Eclipse Neon.

Also, each time I run a project on server, some other projects of my workspace also get deployed by the server.
After tomcat is unable to deploy my target project- ProMgmtPortal, it starts deploying another project- TemplatePMP.

Comment: some errors appears in your project. make sure to set the java build path and add all maven dependencies.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, but I have already done the same.

Comment: Right click on your server and select **'Add and Remove...'**. It will show you the ear files/projects that are currently deployed on the server. Just remove the other project *'TemplatePMP'* if it is present there. It will resolve your second issue.